# Laravel 5.1 getting TokenMismatchException when cookies disabled

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, csrf

I have RESTfull api in my appliication using AJAX PUT request like this:

```
               $.ajax({
               method: "PUT",
               url: "/device/{{ $client->id }}",
               async: false,
               data: {
                        javascript_enabled: $('#javascript-enabled').text(),
                        cookies_enabled: $('#cookies-enabled').text(),
                        device_pixel_ratio: $('#device-pixel-ratio').text(),
                        screen_resolution: $('#screen-resolution').text(),
                        browser_window: $('#browser-window').text(),
                        local_time: $('#local-time').text(),
                        local_time_zone: $('#local-time-zone').text(),
                        _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                      },
               success: function(data)
                        {
                             alert('success');                          
                        },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                   {
                       alert( "Internal server error occurred.");
                   }
           });
```

This code works as it should when I have cookies enabled in browser.

However when I disable cookies I get "TokenMismatchException".

I have solved this by putting this line in "App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken" class:

```
protected $except = [
    'device/*'
];
```

Is there any way of solving this without disabling csrf check for this route?

Comment: Why not having csrf exception for that particular request ?

Comment: Is there any security hole by doing that. I'm actually fine with this approach as long is security intact.

Comment: Yeah, let me give you in detail a bit

Answer (score 1):

You can authenticate the token only if you have `csrf` token present in your request, if not you shall go alternative way like this

Creating a own token which your application ables to identify it

Like having a parameter something like `custom_token` and you shall identify at

`app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php`

**Tip  :** If you do `print_r($request)` you can see all the elements

You shall Authenticate your custom token like this

```
$paramExist=  $request->custom_token;
    #return parent::handle($request, $next);
        if(isset($paramExist))
        {
            $yourSpecialkey ='a2$%$'; #This to check whether the param has the value that you set
            if($paramExist==$yourSpecialKey)
            {
                return $next($request);
            }
            else
            {
                return parent::handle($request, $next);
            }

        }   
        else
        {
            return parent::handle($request, $next);
        }
```

I have given you this temporary matching, you shall use your own way to match/authenticate your token.

Comment: Yes but this way $yourSpecialkey is hard-coded and does not change. If I'm not mistaken Laravel csrf tokens re-generate to prevent hijcking? Real question is why doesn't it work with cookies disabled? I mean cookies or no cookies token is sent anyway.

Comment: Exactly, Laravel not only see the _token from the request, it also sees the header, if you see the headers of your request you can find that cookies,  While you disable the cookies the request won't have the authenticated header which automatically leads to throw exception.

Comment: Yes but it sees _token value in the request. Even with cookies disabled.

Comment: It might not reached the app, not sure the exact reason. If you want to disable it you disable the cookie filter in kernal or middleware

Comment: PS: You shall check it in the array returned by `$request`

Comment: I guess Laravel checks for 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' first. But when I add this to AJAX request still it throws error:  headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
        },

Comment: Then the only way is to check enabling parameters one by one :)

Comment: Can you be more specific please? How to do that?

Comment: Either two way, By exploring the `$request` but it is tedious, You shall take all the parameters in the headers and allow one by one to middleware, You shall also unset those params before it reaches app